# Compiling script files Lua or Python

Tags: python, lua, compilation, obfuscation

I will separate my business code into a script language. it would be Lua or Python. 
My question is my business code written in script file is viewable by others.
Because of script file will not compiled that is open. Anyone can see it.

How can I hide it?
I think if I use Python, it would be compiled (.pyo), but Lua looks like more suitable for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can compile Lua scripts with [`luac`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/luac):

```
luac -s -o yourscript.luc yourscript.lua
```

Using the flag `-s` will also remove debugging information, thus making it also a little bit smaller.

Comment: Sure there are decompilers. See for instance [LuaDec51](http://luadec51.luaforge.net/).

Comment: Note that more common extension is `.luac`, not `.luc`

Comment: @Alexander thanks, out of convenience I always kept using '.luc'... ah well :D.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to hide this easily. You can encrypt and decipher on the fly. The problem is that people will be able to look at you're process memory and see the code clear as day. If you want to prevent people from changing the lua you can create a hash which the text file is checked against on each run.

Answer (score 1):

(For Lua)

Depends on how safe it should be. For keeping out dumb edits you can just change the extension, and configure the path to recognize it anyhow.

For keeping out people who know how to change extensions, you can ship files compiled with luac. For deciphering that you already have to put considerable effort in it.

But to be really save I guess the only way is to encrypt/sign the code, and perhaps modify the core such that it'll only run files who's signature checks out to be OK, or which can be decrypted.

Comment: How is encrypting and signing script code made?

Comment: I don't know. You'll have to look for existing libraries, or code something up yourself.